# jQuery: How hide everything in a div except 2 certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div class="firstclass secondclass">

        <intro><p>This is the first intro...</p></intro>
        <p><button>Button 1</button></p>
        <p>This is the first text paragraph</p>

        <intro><p>This is the second intro...</p></intro>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <p>This is the second text paragraph</p>
        This is another text paragraph, but without the <p> element

    </div>
</div
```

I would like to the the following output usind jQuery:

```
This is the first intro...
Button 1
This is the second intro...Button 2
```

I am trying this code:

```
$('div.item_desc.custom_content :not(intro, button)').hide()
```

What I get instead is:

```
This is another text paragraph, but without the <p> element
```

I am using the custom intro-tag for further processing. Please note, that the button-element once is inside a p-element and the other time not. Also part of the text is not inside a p-element, but I also want this text to be hidden. I definetely need to use the hide command (because of further restrictions). How do I have to modify the my jQuery code?

Comment: Why not just hide everything and then show the two elements again?

Comment: Sorry, code is $('**firstclass.secondclass** :not(intro, button)').hide()

Comment: I don't want to hide everything at start since I want google to be able to read the content. Also hiding everything and showing some elements afterwards again might result in screen flickering

Comment: It would not result in flickering, as the layout is done not before your script terminates

Comment: how about using .filter() ? http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
$('div.item_desc.custom_content').children("intro:not(:first), p:not(:eq(0)), p:not(:eq(1))")
```

However, a simpler solution is to create a class `alwaysshown`

```
<div>
    <div class="firstclass secondclass">

        <intro class="alwaysshown"><p>This is the first intro...</p></intro>
        <p class="alwaysshown"><button>Button 1</button></p>
        <p class="alwaysshown">This is the first text paragraph</p>

        <intro><p>This is the second intro...</p></intro>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <p>This is the second text paragraph</p>
        This is another text paragraph, but without the <p> element

    </div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$('div.item_desc.custom_content').children(":not("alwaysshown")")
```

Comment: `$('.firstclass.secondclass').children(':not(intro, button)').hide()` works, but only the intro und button elements without a surrounding p are hidden. And also the text not surrounded by p elements is still not hidden.

Comment: Why don't you put all the content to be hidden into something, maybe a div and hide that div?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var htmlString = $(".firstclass").html(); 
  var data=''; var getthis='';
 $(".firstclass").find(":button, intro").each(function () {
var getthis = $( this ).html();
data += getthis;             
});
$(".firstclass").html( data );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="firstclass secondclass">

        <intro><p>This is the first intro...</p></intro>
        <p><button>Button 1</button></p>
        <p>This is the first text paragraph</p>

        <intro><p>This is the second intro...</p></intro>
        <button>Button 2</button>
        <p>This is the second text paragraph</p>
        This is another text paragraph, but without the <p> element

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the first intro...

Button 1

This is the first text paragraph

This is the second intro...

Button 2

This is the second text paragraph

This is another text paragraph, but without the

element

Tested code working fine hope it helps.